# SharePoint 2010 Calculated Column in large list throwing error code?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns

I cannot find anything on this error. This calculated column saves ok, but returns -362615635 on select items in a list of about 2500 items. When i go into the item and save (no other changes made) the formula computes correctly. All other calculated columns in the list are calculating correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
=IF(
OR(
    [TypeOfItem]="a"
    ,[TypeOfItem]="b"
    ,[TypeOfItem]="c"
    ,[TypeOfItem]="d/e"
    ,[TypeOfItem]="f"
    ,[TypeOfItem]="g"
    ,[TypeOfItem]="h"
    ,[TypeOfItem]="i"
)
,"Other"
,IF(
    [TypeOfItem]="k"
    ,"One"
    ,IF(
        [TypeOfItem]="(l)"
        ,"Two"
        ,IF(
            [TypeOfItem]="m"
            ,"Three"
            ,IF([
                TypeOfItem]="n"
                ,"Four/Five"
                ,IF(
                    [TypeOfItem]="o (p)"
                    ,"Six"
                    ,IF(
                        [TypeOfItem]="q"
                        ,"Seven"
                        ,"Non")))))))
```

Comment: Also, it appears that the error will come back to the item after some time.

Comment: What is the threadshold set for list?